# React - Error using function to evaluate prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

In the picture below, I'm trying to replace line 120 (which works when not commented) with line 121 so that I can add additional logic in the function on line 98.

However I am seeing error "Invalid value for prop `value`"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an arrow function rather than a value. It should be

```
value={this.getValue(data, name, catIndex, fieldIndex, type, value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getValue(1,2,3,4)` function has 4 parameters. But you called it with 6 parameters.

```
value={()=> this.getValue(data, name, catIndex, fieldIndex, type, value)}
```

PS... do not upload your code with picture. copy and paste is not difficult.